# Missing package error вдруг в проекте

Tags: swift

Работал над проектом и вдруг без всякой причины он перестал компилироваться и теперь получаю вот такие ошибки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал сделать ребилд для проекта, удалить derived data папку, вернуться назад по гиту на комит где это работало, даже сделать еще один клон с репозитория но ничего не помогло.

Что я пропускаю?

Comment: Возможно, что-то случилось с пакетами в SPM. Попробуйте сбросить кэш SPM и т.п.

Comment: @OlegSoloviev да, это помогло! Не знал, что есть такая опция) Закинте как ответ я отмечу

Comment: Да ничего, не стоит)

Answer (score 0):

В итоге решение было вот таким - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68876107/5709159

To reset the cache for a single package:

- Navigate to `~/Library/Caches/org.swift.swiftpm/repositories` and deleting the **folder and lock file** related to the package
- Then, in Xcode, run `File-->Swift Packages-->Reset Package Caches`